# Webdriverio 8 unable to perform CTRL + Multiple clicks

Tags: javascript, ui-automation, wdio

I Have a couple of columns i need to press ctrl button then select multiple columns. I tried many ways but ctrl is not performed.

```
await browser.keys(Key.Control);
    await campaignNameColumn.click();
    await browser.keys(Key.Control);
    await monthColumn.click();
```

Also tried perfromaactions, No luck yet.
I am using WDIO - 8 and node 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this worked for me.

```
    await browser.performActions([
        {
          type: "key",
          id: "keyboard",
          actions: [{ type: "keyDown", value: "" }],
        },
      ]);
    await campaignNameColumn.click();
    await monthColumn.click();
    await browser.performActions([
      {
        type: "key",
        id: "keyboard",
        actions: [{ type: "keyUp", value: "" }],
      },
    ]);
  });
```